# Node.js variables scoping in debugger

Tags: node.js, scope

```
var foo = 0, bar = 0
process.nextTick(function() {
  debugger
})
```

Entering node REPL using `node debug`, and trying to print some variables, I found that `foo` and `bar` can not be accessed either: `ReferenceError: foo is not defined`

```
var foo = 0, bar = 0
process.nextTick(function() {
  console.log(foo)
})

process.nextTick(function() {
  debugger
})
```

But somehow I 'access' `foo` from another async callback function, it became visible, print `bar` still raises `ReferenceError`.

Is it about V8 JIT or Node implementing details?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be nothing wrong with the code, I am not sure how you used the debugger you could try the [node-inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector) for a better debugging experience.

You can always use the console.log to get the current scope value. Same example in browser environment.

```js
var foo = 0, bar = 0
window.setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(foo, bar);
}, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is about V8 "optimizing" the scope -- it leaves out variables that are not actually referenced by the code inside the function, even though they should be in scope.

If you want to see a variable during debug inside the function, you can add a do-nothing line of code that references the variable.  That will force the V8 compiler to make the variable available in that scope.

I wonder whether there is another way?...Whether you can somehow tell V8 to keep more things in scope?